# sending Data over PAN Bluetooth from iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I am developing a bluetooth based application where I want to send/receive data (30Byte string) over PAN profile from iOS application to Mac/Windows application.

I didn't find any tutorial or example to refer.

Comment: By bluetooth do you mean bluetooth low energy I presume?

Comment: Thank you Yoav.

I have an external Bluetooth device which i am using in my WIn/Mac system. 
I want to exchange data between iOS application and Win/Mac Bluetooth device over PAN. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387

But I didnot find any example to refer.

Answer (score 0):

Philip, BLE connections normally send max packets size of 20 bytes; so your looking to send a multi-byte payloads. Here is a good tutorial to get you started.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-core-bluetooth-practical-lesson--mobile-20741

Unfortunately it is in Objective C, not Swift. But you can figure out the translation as you go thru perhaps, the structure would be almost identical; just the syntax changes are needed.

Here is a second, in Swift with a VIDEO, not watched it, but the transcript looks interesting; and perhaps just what your looking for.

https://realm.io/news/yoav-schwartz-corebluetooth-peripherals/